# Convert and create a Google Drive Spreadsheet from a local CSV file via the Google Drive API

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm trying to upload a local CSV-file to Google Drive and display it like a Google Spreadsheet there. However, when I go to my Google Drive and click the link to my file, I can only download it, not view it as a spreadsheet. I've tried using the ?convert=true but the file doesn't get converted. I've also tried using `application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet` as the mime type but noting changes or I get a 400 Bad request response.

> exception 'Google_ServiceException' with message 'Error calling POST
>   https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v2/files?convert=true&uploadType=multipart:
>   (400) Invalid mime type provided' in
>   /var/www/html/twittery/lib/google-api-php-client/src/io/Google_REST.php:66
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /var/www/html/twittery/lib/google-api-php-client/src/io/Google_REST.php(36):
>   Google_REST::decodeHttpResponse(Object(Google_HttpRequest)) #1
>   /var/www/html/twittery/lib/google-api-php-client/src/service/Google_ServiceResource.php(186):
>   Google_REST::execute(Object(Google_HttpRequest)) #2
>   /var/www/html/twittery/lib/google-api-php-client/src/contrib/Google_DriveService.php(484):
>   Google_ServiceResource->__call('insert', Array) #3
>   /var/www/html/twittery/generate_tweets_GSpreadsheet.php(84):
>   Google_FilesServiceResource->insert(Object(Google_DriveFile), Array)
>   #4 {main}

Answer (score 1):

The `mimeType` for uploading a CSV file should be "text/csv".

As per the documentation for [Files:insert](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert), make sure you are giving the same `mimeType` in

```
$file->setMimeType($mimeType);
```

and also

```
$createdFile = $service->files->insert($file, array(
      'data' => $data,
      'mimeType' => $mimeType,
      'convert' => true,
));
```

When creating or updating a file in Google Drive, you can convert the uploaded file into a Google Docs, Sheets or Slides document by using the `convert` query parameter.

You can refer to this [page](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/manage-uploads#convert) to see what are the support conversions for each type of file you upload.